# Do I need a resistor when controlling an ESC with an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, resistors, motor-controller

I am planning to connect one of my arduino's PWM pins to the input pin of an esc and the GND pin to the GND pin of the ESC, which in conjunction with the servo library should allow me to control the ESC. See below for an idea of what I mean.
[esc http://api.ning.com/files/QYxylXSaas588I6jwxcoAJR8lBXneWApDBFHGCoOMg7Ge975QGTPeT0Qinw4ffnFDRoWYf7TcktkQRYX--0YwbQT05HgK*zp/arduino_esc_lucaszanela_com.png](http://api.ning.com/files/QYxylXSaas588I6jwxcoAJR8lBXneWApDBFHGCoOMg7Ge975QGTPeT0Qinw4ffnFDRoWYf7TcktkQRYX--0YwbQT05HgK*zp/arduino_esc_lucaszanela_com.png)

I have seen guides on the internet that just connect everything without a resistor, like pictured above. Is this safe to do? I am not sure what sort of current the signal line would allow and whether it would be in the safe zone of a digital pin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't normally need a resistor. The input to the ESC is a high impedance digital input, just like the inputs on the Arduino.  The current drawn from the Arduino's IO pin would be minuscule.